# Replacing the Host file in Java

Tags: java, windows, file, host, access-denied

So here's my code so far, yes I know it's pretty basic. But what I would Like to accomplish is to Replace the host file located in the System32\drivers\etc folder, the problem I am having in doing this is that I am getting an access denied error. How can I give the program access to make changes within the windows folder, also the class SaveURL  just downloads the file and uses two strings to pass the name and download location through the function saveImage. How can I give myself access? Thanks in advance I truly appreciate it.

```
private void jButton7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        String destinationHosts = "hosts";
        String urlHosts = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/awdvoprxyo7r2q6/hosts?dl=1";
        Object hostOptions[] = {"Replace", "Close"};
        File fileHosts = new File(destinationHosts);
        File dirHost = new File("hosts");
        boolean dirHosts = dirHost.mkdir();
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe \\Windows\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
            jTextArea2.append("Opening Host File \n");
            int hostFile = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, "Would you like to replace the Hosts File?",
                    "Yes or No", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, null, hostOptions, hostOptions[0]);
            if (hostFile == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) {
                jTextArea2.append("Downloading New Host File");
                SaveUrl.saveImage(urlHosts, destinationHosts);
                fileHosts.renameTo(new File(dirHost, fileHosts.getName()));
                Path source = Paths.get("\\hosts\\hosts");
                Path target = Paths.get("\\Windows\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\");
                Files.copy(source, target);
                jTextArea2.append("Host file replaced");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ToolKit1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Naturally you will get permission problems when attempting to modify hosts. Are you running the program as Administrator? **I do not believe that using JAVA you will be able to edit/replace the file for security reasons.

Comment: This might help you, just check anyways http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html

Comment: Thank you for all your help, the link above was helpful as well, but does not necessarily fix my problem.